# Got blue camera screen with CaptureMedia on UWP

Tags: camera, uwp

I got blue preview screen when start camera many time on UWP. I used MediaCapture and CaptureElement to implement camera screen. Do you guys have any experience with this issue, please help me.

Thanks you so much!

Comment: How did you use `MediaCapture` and `CaptureElement`? You can refer to [Capture photos and video with MediaCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-mediacapture) and also try with [Basic camera app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit). It works well in my device.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT I am using this sample. It works ok unless I start and close camera screen many time.

Comment: @duynt Could you please tell us the model of your testing device? Looks like this issue can only be reproduced on several devices

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT I am testing on Lumina 435 and Lumina 430. This issue happens only after many time close and restart camera screen.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. This issue happens because of device rotates many times when close-reopen camera screens continuously. I fixed it by change camera's initialization orientation to Portrait as same as application's.